# jquery display multiple json objects returned from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i know that this question is a bit childish but i am unable to find the correct solution to this problem...

i am using jquery and ajax call to user search functionality in website with php returning json objects...

when i search users using php file, if the json return is only one array, the jquery prints it on the screen, but when multiple results are returned, i don't know to print them out....

here are the results returned from the php:

```
{"search":"10 
junaid 
saleem 
junaid@yahoo.com 

"}{"search":"13 
zzz 
aaa 
zzz@yahoo.com 

"}
```

and here is the jquery webpage:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require("secure_scripts/getusers.php");
require("secure_scripts/getdp.php");
require("secure_scripts/getusersinfo.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header("location: index.php");
}else{
    $zxcv_lgn = base64_encode($_SESSION['id']);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome <?php echo getusers("first_name"); ?> | Addressbook.com</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#search_button").click(function(){
                    $("#search_button").click(function(){ $("#console_loader").hide(); });
                    $("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' id='ajax-loader' />");
                    var send = $("#search").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "secure_scripts/search_users.php",
                        data: {search: send},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg){
                            $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                                $("#console_loader img").remove();
                                $("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html(msg.search);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                });
            });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <p><a href="index.php"><img src="images/header_logo.png" /><span>AddressBook™</span></a></p>


    </div>

    <div id="wrapper" align="center">

        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="top_nav">
                    <div class="userinfo"><span class="user_title">Welcome <?php echo getusers("first_name")." ".getusers("last_name"); ?></span></div>
                    <div class="search">
                        <form onsubmit="return false" id="search_form">
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="search_box" id="search" placeholder="Type in to search...">
                            <input type="button" id="search_button" class="sea" name="search_submit"value="search">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="left_nav">
                    <div id="dp"><img src="<?php echo getdp(); ?>"></div>
                    <div class="left_nav_links">Profile</div>
                    <div class="left_nav_links">Contacts</div>
                    <div class="left_nav_links">Settings</div>
                    <div class="left_nav_links">privacy</div>
                    <div class="left_nav_links">logout</div>
                </div>
                <div id="console">
                    <div id="console_top_nav">Your Contacts:</div>
                    <div id="console_content">
                        <div id="console_loader" style="display: none;"></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <div id="links"><ul><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li><a href="about">About</a></li><li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li></ul></div>
            <div id="copyrights">&copy; 2014 Addressbook.com All Rights Reserved</div>
        </div>  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

whenevery only one object is returned from php, like:

```
{"search":"13 
zzz 
aaa 
zzz@yahoo.com 

"}
```

it works perfectly, but not with multiple json objects....

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are returning valid json? You should `json_encode()` and `echo` your results at the end once (for example an array that contains everything you want to return), not do that multiple times.

Comment: In your `success` function, try putting then entire response inside of `$.each` so you'll run the function for each response, not just the first. [Something like this](http://diffiebosman.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/how-to-return-multiple-json-objects-from-php-to-jquery-with-ajax/)

Comment: +1 @CodyReichert - $.each() will cycle through your json objects and allow you to work with each one instead of just returning the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "secure_scripts/search_users.php",
  data: {search: send},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg){
    $.each(function() {
      $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#console_loader img").remove();
        $("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html(msg.search);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

We're adding `$.each()` method to the success function in order to run it for each JSON object that gets returned, not just the first.

[Here's the jQuery.each() doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for further reading.

*edited for clarity*

Comment: if the json is received as an array of objects, i would recommending using $.each(function (index, item){} and access the object via item.search instead using msg.search

Comment: i don't know to use that, can you please guide me @HowardRenollet

Comment: @JunaidSaleem - I've posted a more detailed explanation as an answer.  Please let me know if you have any other questions or need further assistance.

Comment: okay, i've tried the link that you posted and applied that method on my script, but i got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.....
on this line: $.each(results['Users'], function(key, val) {

Comment: okay, mr @CodyReichert thanks for showing me the right way and i've found the error, the error was: this ->: $.each(results['Users'], function(key, val),,,, should be like this ->: $.each(results.Users, function(key, val), thanks for help again :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery's `.each()` method, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_button").click(function(){
        $("#search_button").click(function(){ $("#console_loader").hide(); });
        $("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' id='ajax-loader' />");
        var send = $("#search").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "secure_scripts/search_users.php",
            data: {search: send},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $.each(function (index, item) {
                    $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $("#console_loader img").remove();
                        $("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html(item.search);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When your json is received, it is more than likely an array of objects

```
[{"search":"10 
    junaid 
    saleem 
    junaid@yahoo.com 

    "}{"search":"13 
    zzz 
    aaa 
    zzz@yahoo.com 
"}]
```

Therefore, by using `$.each()` to loop through the collection and return the value `(index, item)` you can get the object's value by referencing it like so:

```
$("#console_loader").fadeIn("slow").html(item.search);
```

since json is returning a JavaScript object literal.